# How to bring the XML from Pentaho report

Tags: xml, xsd, olap, pentaho, mondrian

After I look around the Pentaho application/plugin. There're many applications/plugins that related to Pentaho report. Does anyone know that if I want to have the XML that be able to link the Pentaho report(even my database to build the report), what application or plugin that necessary for me to use for bring the XML out and using in the third party application?

Answer (score 0):

as i have explained in this answer

[How I manage the sample datasource in Saiku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828780/how-i-manage-the-sample-datasource-in-saiku/15830354?noredirect=1#comment22596471_15830354)

-you have to create JNDI Connection for the database in admin panel after that only you will able visualize xml file in bi server user panel.