# How I manage the sample datasource in Saiku

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I installed the Saiku as a plugin in Pentaho 4.8. Saiku comes with the sample data which is SteelWheels. The user is able to choose "Select a cube" in the dropdown box. I just need to know how can I modify the data in that sample data? Where is the file which contains the datastore? And how does the database communicate with the XML file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a cube in pentaho schema workbench or in pentaho BI Server..
If you are creating it in Schema Workbench then you have to publish it after you publish your schema into bi server you will directly able to see that selected cube into Saiku Server..

Comment: I look into the file name SampleData.mondrian.xml and I cofused that how this file connect with the database?

Comment: if you downloaded BI Server and extracted the zip file you will going to find one folder called administration-console.
- in that folder you find set-pentaho-env.bat file for windows and set-pentaho-env.sh file linux
- run that file over their you find the default connection for Sample-Data.